# How to parallel sort and slice a large nested dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, numba

Be a large nested dictionary with the following structure

```py
# {
#     "query_1": {
#         "doc_1": 0.27525704173232723,
#         "doc_2": 0.05115370517104112,
#         "doc_3": 0.684077731862703,
#         "doc_4": 0.8593173782232113,
#         "doc_5": 0.9992261057642471,
#         "doc_6": 0.8927443913799646,
#         "doc_7": 0.21853726164833975,
#         "doc_8": 0.20343449721373175,
#         "doc_9": 0.3671854317362193,
#         "doc_10": 0.5517113596197711,
#         "doc_11": 0.1882548003666461,
#         "doc_12": 0.044734783865907124,
#         "doc_13": 0.22633588060935117,
#         "doc_14": 0.2578317547900737,
#         "doc_15": 0.5659508960653867
#     },
#     ...
#     "query_1587658": {
#         "doc_1": 0.10856609385238025,
#         "doc_2": 0.016464788372524297,
#         "doc_3": 0.3566483096640577,
#         "doc_4": 0.5400913407418702,
#         "doc_5": 0.17848721844101811,
#         "doc_6": 0.42536942094534014,
#         "doc_7": 0.5080529426125224,
#         "doc_8": 0.3461002807821024,
#         "doc_9": 0.24761391133009103,
#         "doc_10": 0.6286192869283476,
#         "doc_11": 0.08574801929277642,
#         "doc_12": 0.5384879539476498,
#         "doc_13": 0.44215582705669476,
#         "doc_14": 0.05529319806340971,
#         "doc_15": 0.10878796076603192
#     }
# }
```

representing a ranking. It is necessary to sort the inner dictionaries (the retrieved documents) and select the `top_k` items for each query. The following algorithm performs this ordering sequentially:

```py
import json
import heapq

top_k=5
for query_idx, docs_scores in ranking.items():
    ranking[query_idx] = {k: v for k, v in heapq.nlargest(top_k, docs_scores.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])} 
print(json.dumps(ranking, indent=4)) 
# {
#     "query_1": {
#         "doc_5": 0.9992261057642471,
#         "doc_6": 0.8927443913799646,
#         "doc_4": 0.8593173782232113,
#         "doc_3": 0.684077731862703,
#         "doc_15": 0.5659508960653867
#     },
#     ...

#     },
#     "query_1587658": {
#         "doc_10": 0.6286192869283476,
#         "doc_4": 0.5400913407418702,
#         "doc_12": 0.5384879539476498,
#         "doc_7": 0.5080529426125224,
#         "doc_13": 0.44215582705669476
#     }
# }
```

As the ordering of a query is independent of another query, could you provide an approach to parallelize the above algorithm?

Comment: How big is your actual data: queries, docs, top_k? Also, are you only looking for Numba solutions? What about other solutions, like simple multiprocessing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if [numba](/questions/tagged/numba) is right tool for the task (perhaps if you can transform the Python dictionaries to numpy arrays then there can be speedups):

But you can simply speed up the script with:

```py
def process(ranking):
    for k in ranking:
        ranking[k] = dict(
            sorted(ranking[k].items(), key=lambda i: i[1], reverse=True)[:5]
        )
```

---

Simple benchmark:

```py
import heapq
from random import random, seed
from timeit import timeit


def create_dict(n=1587658, _seed=42):
    seed(_seed)

    out = {
        f"query_{i}": {f"doc_{n}": random() for n in range(1, 16)}
        for i in range(1, n + 1)
    }
    return out


def variant_1(ranking):
    top_k = 5
    for query_idx, docs_scores in ranking.items():
        ranking[query_idx] = {
            k: v
            for k, v in heapq.nlargest(
                top_k, docs_scores.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]
            )
        }


def variant_2(ranking):
    for k in ranking:
        ranking[k] = dict(
            sorted(ranking[k].items(), key=lambda i: i[1], reverse=True)[:5]
        )

t1 = timeit("variant_1(d)", setup="d=create_dict()", globals=globals(), number=1)
t2 = timeit("variant_2(d)", setup="d=create_dict()", globals=globals(), number=1)

print(t1)
print(t2)
```

On my computer (Python 3.11/AMD 5700x) this prints:

```
5.448211211245507
3.5935627752915025
```